# Is there a more elegant way to catch a generic exception than using try-catch block?

Tags: javascript, beginner

Here are two sample blocks of my code:

```
function FindTheNumberOfAddedItems ( PageObj, ItemType )
{
    var localPageObj = PageObj;
    var localItemType = ItemType;
    var numberOfAddedItems = 0;
    var NROCssSelector  = "div[class='assessment-stub list-top-border-colour-1 clearfix box-shadow'] strong";
    var OROCssSelector  = "div[class='assessment-stub list-top-border-colour-2 clearfix box-shadow'] strong";
    var RCCssSelector  = "div[class='assessment-stub list-top-border-colour-3 clearfix box-shadow'] strong";

    try {
        switch (localItemType)
        {
            case "NRO":
                numberOfAddedItems = ParseNumberOutOfString(localPageObj.QuerySelector(NROCssSelector).innerText);
                break;
            case "ORO":
                numberOfAddedItems = ParseNumberOutOfString(localPageObj.QuerySelector(OROCssSelector).innerText);
                break;
            case "RC":
                numberOfAddedItems = ParseNumberOutOfString(localPageObj.QuerySelector(RCCssSelector).innerText);
                break;
            default:
                Log.Message("Invalid item type");
        }
    }
    catch (err){
        Log.Message("Can not find then number of added items.");
    }
    return numberOfAddedItems;
}

function ParseNumberOutOfString ( TextString )
{
    var localTextString = TextString;
    var numberOnlyRegexPattern = /\d+/g;

    try {
        return localTextString.match(numberOnlyRegexPattern);
    }
    catch (err){
        Log.Message("Can not parse number out of string.");
    }
}
```

I have used `try`-`catch` blocks for both functions (and for the rest of all of my functions) in case there is anything wrong with my code.

Come to think about it, having `try`-`catch` blocks everywhere is kind of messy. Is there another more elegant way to do it?

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@HristoYank is correct, you shouldn't catch exceptions that you can't handle. What you are doing is basically just ignoring the error, which will make it difficult to trace bugs.

If I call a method called `ParseNumberOutOfString`, I will expect to get a number back. If the function can't return a number, I need to know that, so that I can react appropriately.

Depending on the situation, I may want to use a default value, ask the user for new input, or abort with an appropriate error message.

If the function just swallows the error and logs it somewhere, I will continue processing with invalid data (`null` in this case), which will result in all sorts of bugs down the line. As only a generic error message and no stracktrace is logged, debugging will also be rather difficult.

**Misc**

- `match` doesn't actually throw an exception, so you will never get into the catch.
- don't uppercase your variable names.

Answer (score 1):

I have to strongly agree with @tim and @HristoYankov on this one - "swallowing" errors like this is *almost always* a bad practice (unless you genuinely don't care if the function fails for some reason).

First, when you catch an exception, as others have indicated, you should log all of the details of the exception (e.g. stack trace, what the argument was, etc.); right now all your log says is that the argument couldn't be parsed as a number for some unspecified reason, which'll make debugging difficult. What exactly does "couldn't be parsed as a number" mean - was the argument null? Was the argument an unexpected type? Did the string just not match the regex? How did you get to that state in the first place? Etc. There are lots of reasons that this *could* fail and the log message gives no indication of why or how it did or what exactly the program is supposed to do about it.

I'd suggest considering the possible exception cases and what you'd do about them. For example, if this failed because the user tried to enter something like "123hk" as a number, then the program should *not* try to continue with this kind of input - it should prompt the user to enter a valid string.

Finally, I did notice that you said you included the try/catch blocks "in case there is anything wrong with my code." As a general rule, try/catch blocks shouldn't be included to compensate for bugs elsewhere in code - just fix the bug. The purpose of a try/catch block and exceptions is to handle exceptional cases - for example, if you try to contact a server but the server isn't responding. If there's a bug somewhere, you *want* it to throw an exception so you can fix it - that's the kind of thing you should catch and fix with testing (not with try/catch blocks).

Also, as written the ParseNumberOutOfString method itself *can't* throw an exception (since it "swallows" all exceptions too) - the only way that this could happen is if `localPageObj.QuerySelector(NROCssSelector).innerText` throws an exception. Think about the circumstances under which this could throw an exception - if `QuerySelector` throws an exception or returns `null` or if `localPageObj` is `null`. At least two of the three of those either shouldn't happen or, if they can, should be explicitly tested for.

As a final point, if these methods are consumable by other developers, you should do some kind of validation of your arguments to make sure that people are using it properly.